# Как сделать фильтр по нескольким параметрам для запроса к БД со связанными таблицами?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel5.4

У меня есть набор фильтров: **name**, **email**, **role**, **project**, **subproject**, **date_from**, **date_to** и т.п. Нужно сделать выборку из БД таким образом, чтобы все заполненные фильтры участвовали в фильтрации.

Все усложняется еще и тем, что имя и дата находятся в таблице **day_reports**. Остальные же параметры лежат в связанной таблице **elementary_reports**. Как здесь лучше сделать выборку из таблицы? Желательно через eloquent.

```
class DayReport extends Model
{
protected $guarded = [];
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at','reportdate'];

public function elementary()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ElementaryReport', 'day_reports_id', 'id');
}
```

Я понимаю, что нужно использовать конструкцию типа этой:

```
DayReport::with('elementary')
```

Пробовал сделать таким образом:

```
$result =  DayReport::select('username')->with('elementary')
        ->when(!empty($filters['name']) , function ($query) use($filters) {
            return $query->where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.$filters['name'].'%');
        })->get();
```

Но как добавить еще один/несколько **when** для параметров в таблице **elementary_reports**?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример фильтров:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $query = User::where('company_id', $request->input('company_id'));

        if ($request->has('last_name'))
        {
            $query->where('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('last_name') . '%');
        }

        if ($request->has('name'))
        {
            $query->where(function ($q) use ($request)
            {
                return $q->where('first_name', 'LIKE', $request->input('name') . '%')
                    ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('name') . '%');
            });
        }

        $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($request)
        {
            return $q->whereIn('id', $request->input('roles'));
        })
            ->whereHas('clients', function ($q) use ($request)
            {
                return $q->whereHas('industry_id', $request->input('industry'));
            });

        return $query->get();
    }

}
```

А вот тот же пример но если использовать [эту](https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter) библиотеку:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return User::filter($request->all())->get();
    }

}
```

В этой библиотеке все настраивается и она самая популярная для этой цели.